# Angular web app with asp.net web api hosted on AppHarbor displays wrong web page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, appharbor

I've been working on a web app with angular and asp.net web api in Visual Studio 2015.

When I run the solution in `VS2015`, I get two tabs in chrome - one for my angular client side application and one for the asp.net web api (which was automatically generated when I started the project).

These two run on different ports of localhost. I have successfully deployed the project to `appharbor`, however, when I click on `'go to my application'`,

the web pages for the asp.net web api are displayed, and I can't seem to access the ones for my client side application.

How can I change this so that the host url displays my client side application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a simple thing really. AppHarbor can only deploy one website per application and was deploying my asp.net api automatically generated website instead of my angular one. The solution was to copy my solution file, rename it 'AppHarbor.sln', and then remove the API project.

Steps outlined here:
https://blog.appharbor.com/2012/06/25/deploying-solutions-with-multiple-web-projects-on-appharbor